# Apache.poi save to Excel. Associate data with column names

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-poi

I have a method that accepts dynamic data and saves it to an excel file:

```
private void saveExcel(List<ExplosureDto> list, List<String> columns, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

                    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Reports");
                    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);

                    List<Object> namesForRowZero = new ArrayList<>(columns);
                   // Map<XSSFCell, Integer> namesForRowZero1 = new HashMap<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < namesForRowZero.size(); i++) {
                        Cell cell = row.createCell(i);
                        cell.setCellValue(String.valueOf(namesForRowZero.get(i)));
                        cell.setCellStyle(excelStylesDtoService.greenColor(workbook));

                        namesForRowZero1.put(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(i), i);
                    }

                        int second = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;

                        for (ExplosureDto dto : list) {
                            for (ChildExplosure childExplosure : dto.getChildExplosures()) {
                               
                                    row = sheet.createRow(second);
                                    Cell cell1 = row.createCell(second);
                                    BigDecimal amount = childExplosure.getAmount();
                                    sheet.setColumnWidth(second, 20 * 256);
                                    cell1.setCellValue(amount.doubleValue());
                                    cell1.setCellStyle(excelStylesDtoService.styleBorder(workbook));
                                        second++;
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    String report = "C:/download/Report.xlsx";
                    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(report);
                    workbook.write(outputStream);
                    workbook.close();

                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

The column names are the dates that the user enters.
These names (dates) I get correctly.
But the sums themselves come out like this:

```
   2022-01  |     2022-02    |   2022-03    |   2022-04    |   2022-05   |
------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
            |   334008,0972  |              |              |             |
            |                |  334008,0972 |              |             |
            |                |              |  334008,0972 |             |
            |                |              |              | 334008,0972 |
            |                |              |              |             |  334008,0972
```

However, the question is how to tie these dates to the amounts that refer to them.
Of course it should look like this:

```
   2022-01  |     2022-02    |   2022-03    |   2022-04    |   2022-05   |
------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
            |                | 334008,0972  | 334008,0972  | 334008,0972 |
            |                |  334008,0972 | 334008,0972  |             |
334008,0972 | 334008,0972    | 334008,0972  |  334008,0972 |             |
            | 334008,0972    |              |              | 334008,0972 |
            |                |              |              |             |
```

I had an idea to do it via Map (I commented out this line in the code). But I can't do it right

Comment: `row = sheet.createRow(second);` you re-create the row for every column. You either want it for every `ExplosureDto` or for every `ChildExplosure`

Comment: @Alexander For every ChildExplosure

Comment: Then move it one line up and you should be good

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I tried different options, it doesn't work

Comment: "Doesn't work" is too broad. Also `Cell cell1 = row.createCell(second);` -> you don't iterate the columns. You need a counter for the row number and one for the columns. Column counter must be reset whenever you create a new row

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Thanks for the answer!
Can you write a code so that I accept it as an answer to my question?